# Display HTML content as a Text in UIWebView

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am working in application in which user can send email, and while displaying the email we are getting `HTML`, And in that `HTML` tags we are getting email text and some formatting like paragraphs, bold fields. Currently I have used `UIWebView` but now my problem is that if any user has send some `HTML` input at that time I need to display that like simple text only.

In the response HTML I have some text to consider as a HTML and it is working fine with web view. But what if some one ask me for HTML code to send as a email, I type some HTML code (lets take a Form design with ) in email message and when I show it in WebView it shows the form not the text I typed.

I want to mark something so marked html content displays as a text and rest of HTML content may take its effect.

Comment: could you provide an example of what is going on? what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to escape special characters in your HTML code.

For instance the following HTML

```
<p>Hello world!</p>
```

should be represented as:

```
&lt;p&gt;Hello world!&lt;/p&gt;
```

Here's a Swift project that simplifies this for you:
https://github.com/Halotis/EscapeHTML